# macro: value is not of type LIST

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am trying to write a macro that will [`eazygnuplot:plot`](https://github.com/guicho271828/eazy-gnuplot) many series at once. Ideally, I wanted to write something like `(plotlists lists)`, where `lists` looks something like this:

```
'(((57 91)) ((83 1) (90 8) (78 18)) ((42 19)))
```

That is, `lists` is a list of `k` lists of pairs (more concretely, this is a list of points on a plane, after clustering with k-means). The macro I mentioned is supposed to expand into something like:

```
(eazy-gnuplot:plot (lambda ()
                     (dolist (p l1)
                       (format t "~&~A ~A" (first p) (second p)))))
(eazy-gnuplot:plot (lambda ()
                     (dolist (p l2)
                       (format t "~&~A ~A" (first p) (second p)))))
```

...and so forth. My idea was to write something like this:

```
(defmacro plotlists (lists)
  `(progn ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (ll)
                        '(eazy-gnuplot:plot
                             (lambda ()
                                (dolist (p ll)
                                  (format t "~&~A ~A" (first p) (second p))))))
                    lists)))
```

That macro is called by a function `scatter` like this:

```
(defun scatter (lists)
  (eazy-gnuplot:with-plots (*standard-output* :debug t)
    (eazy-gnuplot:gp-setup :terminal '(:qt))
    (plotlists lists)
    (format t "~&pause mouse button1;~%")))
```

However, compiling the function on SBCL gives several warnings and errors ("the variable LISTS is defined but never used -- how??"; and "the value LISTS is not of type LIST"). Also, according to the compiler, for some reason, the `"~&pause mouse button1;~%"` part is "unreachable code" and is deleted on compilation. How come?

I know very little about Lisp, but this is pretty puzzling to me. Anyone have any ideas on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, apparently I was approaching this totally wrong. There's no need to use a macro for that, as made apparent by running `MACROEXPAND-1` on the expression. The value of `LISTS` is not of type `LIST` because it's just a `SYMBOL`, which is the only thing available at macro expansion time. I simply replaced the macro with another `DOLIST`:

```
(defun scatter (lists)
  (eazy-gnuplot:with-plots (*standard-output* :debug t)
    (eazy-gnuplot:gp-setup :terminal '(:qt))
    (dolist (cluster lists)
      (eazy-gnuplot:plot (lambda ()
                           (dolist (point cluster)
                             (format t "~&~A ~A" (first point) (second point))))))
    (format t "~&pause mouse button1;~%")))
```